# Set an ubuntu package for later upgrade

Tags: linux, apt-get

When running 'sudo apt-get upgrade', there are sometimes kernel files that 'have been kept back' so they are not upgraded automatically. Is there a way to mark other packages so they get into this category? Android-studio, for instance, is a large package and I would like to upgrade it only when I'm on a fast internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold packages to specific versions.  When you are ready to upgrade, remove the hold and upgrade.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

For "big things" like Android Studio and various IDEs I typically break my own rule of "always use the package manager" and install from a .tar.gz or similar directly from the vendor site, putting stuff under /opt/nameOfThing-version .  So my Netbeans install is at `/opt/netbeans-8.1`, my Android Studio is at `/opt/AndroidStudio-2.3` and so on. Each gets updated manually when I want, and I can occasionally use multiple versions for maintaining compatibility with both work and school stuff